# Is There A More Efficient Ways Of Doing This

Tags: mysql

I want to update one table’s row with the contents of another tables two rows. Is there a more efficient way rather than locking the table with 2 alias (`new_data AS x & y`).

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;

START TRANSACTION;

LOCK TABLES
1_products_speech WRITE,
new_data as x WRITE,
new_data as y WRITE;

UPDATE 1_products_speech 
SET 
    v1 = (SELECT 
            data_blob
        FROM
            new_data as x
        WHERE
            id = 1),
    v2 = (SELECT 
            data_blob
        FROM
            new_data as y
        WHERE
            id = 2)
WHERE
    fk_products_id = 1890;

COMMIT;

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: why even alias at all

Comment: If I try to use the same Alias on both nested selects then I get the Error Code: 1100. Table 'x' was not locked with LOCK TABLES

Comment: i mean, well for one glad to see what bohemian wrote below, but as you wrote it, if you did not alias at all, the nests are isolated from one another and a single lock on just new_data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql supports multi-table update statements, so you could re-write your query as:

```
UPDATE 1_products_speech 
JOIN new_data x ON id = 1
JOIN new_data y ON id = 2
SET
  v1 = x.data_blob,
  v2 = y.data_blob
WHERE fk_products_id = 1890;
```

Because the joins to the other tables don't depended on a value in the main table, I doubt it is more efficient in terms of performance, although it may be considered more efficient in terms of coding.